# Trying to manually decode PGM image file. Where does my code fail?

Tags: c

I'm having trouble writing a code that turns an RGB image (in this case a .ppm file) into an image in grayscale (.pgm output file).
The code:

```
    int i;

    typedef struct {
        unsigned char r, g, b;
    } rgb;

    FILE *fd;
    FILE *gr;
    rgb *img;

    unsigned width, height;

    fd = fopen("rocks.ppm", "r");

    fscanf(fd, "%d %d\n", &width, &height);

    img = calloc(3, width * height);
    fread(img, 3, width * height, fd);

    unsigned char *gray;

    double len = width * height;

    gray = calloc(1, len);

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        gray[i] = img[i].r * 0.2126 + img[i].g * 0.7152 + img[i].b * 0.0722;
    }

    fclose(fd);

    gr = fopen("rocks_gray.pgm", "w");

    fprintf(gr, "P5\n%d %d\n255\n", width, height);

    fwrite(gray, 1, len, gr);

    fclose(gr);
```

When I compile and run the code the image file created comes out completely black, and I can't put my finger on the problem.
Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: `fscanf` should be `fscanf(fd, "P6\n%d %d\n255\n", &width, &height)`

Comment: @jvx8ss The last `\n"` in `"P6%d %d\n255\n"` risks reading more than 1 byte.  Sure that is OK?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I'm not good with `fscanf` formatting but the first few bytes of a ppm file is `"P6\nwidth height\n255\n"` Is that wrong `fscanf` format?

Comment: @jvx8ss Yes.  `"\n"`, `"\t"`, `" "`, in a `fscanf()` format all do the same thing: scan for 0 _or more_ whitespaces - thus possible consuming the following binary pixel data. . Could use `"P6\n%d %d\n255%*1[\n]"` so that after 255, scan for exactly 1 `\n` and consume it.   .ppm is a strange ASCII/binary format.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I see, so if the first byte the image binary was 0x0A it would break right?

Comment: @jvx8ss Yes, or `' '`, `'\r'`, `'\t'`, and a few others.

Comment: Daniel Santos,  `gray[i] = img[i].r * 0.2126 + img[i].g * 0.7152 + img[i].b * 0.0722;` could be replaced with `gray[i] = ((img[i].r * 2126 + img[i].g * 7152 + img[i].b * 722) *2 + 1)/20000;` if you want to avoid FP math.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here: `fscanf(fd, "%d %d\n", &width, &height);`

The **ppm** file starts with `P6` so the `fscanf()` fails to convert anything and returns `0`, leaving `width` and `height` unchanged, hence uninitialized, causing the rest of the program to have undefined behavior.

You should change the `fscanf()` and check the return value.

More generally, you should always check for errors that may cause undefined behavior and report the problem with a meaningful error message.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned char r, g, b;
} rgb;

int main() {
    const char *input_file = "rocks.ppm";
    FILE *fd = fopen(input_file, "rb");
    if (fd == NULL) {
        perror(input_file);
        return 1;
    }

    unsigned width, height;
    char newline[2];

    // Accept binary pixmaps:
    // P6 <whitespace> width <whitespace> height <whitespace> 255 <single space> <raster>
    if (fscanf(fd, "P6 %u %u 255%1[ \t\r\n\v\f]", &width, &height, newline) != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: invalid source format\n", input_file);
        fclose(fd);
        return 1;
    }

    unsigned len = width * height;
    rgb *img = calloc(len, 3);
    if (img == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate memory for %u pixels\n", len);
        fclose(fd);
        return 1;
    }
    if (fread(img, 3, len, fd) != len) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: cannot read %u pixels\n", input_file, len);
        fclose(fd);
        return 1;
    }
    fclose(fd);

    unsigned char *gray = calloc(len, 1);
    if (gray == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate memory for %u gray scales\n", len);
        return 1;
    }

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        // using non standard gray scale conversion
        gray[i] = img[i].r * 0.2126 + img[i].g * 0.7152 + img[i].b * 0.0722;
    }

    const char *output_file = "rocks_gray.pgm";
    FILE *gr = fopen(output_file, "wb");
    if (gr == NULL) {
        perror(output_file);
        return 1;
    }

    fprintf(gr, "P5\n%u %u\n255\n", width, height);
    fwrite(gray, 1, len, gr);
    fclose(gr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd go for `size_t` `width, height` to handle large files.  But likely good enough for OP.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: you are correct, but I settled for `unsigned width, height;` and `len`, to avoid the `%zu` conversion specifiers and keep the code simple.

Comment: chqrlie, Yes, of course.